# highlighting the edge created by overlaping meshes

Tags: mesh, modifiers

id like to highlight the edge, created by a plane while moving through an 3d funktion. I cant figure out, how i could create an special material for this line or create an Spline wich i could bevel. Im a bit stuck.

[image: edgeline]

any ideas? thx

Comment: Your image is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Extrude the plane, it needs to be manifold.

   [image]
2. Add a boolean modifier to it with the Function object as the **object**.
   [image]
3. Group the plane object, enable Freestyle on the Group with **border** rendering.[image]

[image]
[image]